# Using custom JavaScript

Tags: theming, javascript

Is there a location where I can drop in a custom JavaScript file in Drupal 7.x?

It just includes simple event actions for menus, and I don't want to edit the theme/module files.

Or do I have to just add the "include" hook to the theme/module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's three places where you can put your Javascript resources:

1. Your theme folder. If you have a theme in your site named Mechaflash, you could put it inside Mechaflash/js or just in `Mechaflash`. In order to make the theme folder "more organized", generally people create a dedicated `js` folder. I would place Javascript in the theme when your Javascript delivers functionality specific to the theme / presentation layer, or that it affects all of the site (global).
2. In one of your custom modules. The same principle of creating a dedicated `js` folder can also apply here. I generally put JS on the modules when the Javascript is delivering a very specialized functionality relevant to a specific module. It also allows you to "package" your Javascript with your modules and to pass this modules to other sites (i.e. a modular approach).
3. In the site's library folder. I've never done this personally. Not because it's bad, but because I think it's reserved for more complex functionality that other modules (and themes) can use. A good example, the JQuery UI library.

You can do all of this using the [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) function. Here are some examples of how to add a JS file from a module:

```
// Add a "javascript library" from your module. JS_LIBRARY is an integer constant with a value of -100, which means that `mecha_library.js` will be added before `mecha_ninja.js`.
$module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module');
drupal_add_js($module_path. 'js/mecha_library.js', array('group' => JS_LIBRARY));

// Add a javascript file from your module. The default 'group' here is JS_DEFAULT, so mecha_ninja.js will be added after mecha_library.js.
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module');
drupal_add_js($path. 'js/mecha_ninja.js', 'file');
```

Comment: The libraries API essentially lets a module/theme declare that it Wants to use a library, and it will be loaded if anyone has declared the need.  It cuts down on potentially loading things twice, or loading things when they aren't needed.

Comment: And that counts as a 4th approach, or if you will, as a substitute to the 3rd approach that I mentioned above, because it would generally be preferable to use the Library API rather than specifying a library with drupal_add_js(), for the very reasons @MPD mentions above.

Comment: I'm attempting #1. I went to the theme's folder but there wasn't a js folder. If I create one and drop the file into it, it doesn't load on the page. Do I have to include the drupal_add_js() function no matter what? If so which file do I add it to?

Comment: You could call drupal_add_js() in template.php. However when working with the theme, it is much easier to add the **relative path** to your javascript file to your theme's .info file.

Comment: @Mechaflash just remember you can't just drop a JS file in your theme, you need to declare it in your `.info` file hence modify your theme. Also theses changes will be deleted on each theme update so you'd rather consider a [sub-theme](http://drupal.org/node/225125).

Comment: I went ahead and used the template.php route. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: going the info file route now actually =D

Answer (score 3):

Drupal 7 allows `scripts[]` and `stylesheets[]` in both theme.info and module.info files.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is in your theme .info file.

You just need to add scripts[] = myscript.js in to the .info file of the theme you are using.

[More info](http://drupal.org/node/171205#scripts)